# How to efficiently iterate over std::(unordered)set when deleting items from it?

Tags: c++, set

I have a bunch of elements stored in some container. Their order does not matter for me.

I iterate over my container and check some predicate - P for each of the elements. If P is true - remove the element from the container. If P is false - just go to the next one.
If at least one element was deleted during the iteration I repeat this process. There is a chance that on a new iteration the P will be true for the elements for which it was false during previous iterations.

I've written a code for this

```
std::unordered_map<T, T> container;
auto it = container.begin();
while (it != container.end()) {
    if (predicate(*it)) {
        it = container.erase(it);
    } else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

I have a question:
Is there a better way to do this (both in terms of clean code and it's time efficiency) considering I have about 500 elements in my container.

Comment: Please don't add a list of questions to your question, it will get closed for lack of focus. Please try to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: The code you've shared does not match your description. It does not repeat the process when an element is deleted.

Comment: You are checking the `predicate` on `*mask`, which has nothing to do with the `it`erator you use to loop on `container`, as far as we can tell from the non-compilable code that you shared. In short, the code you present has little to do with the description.

Comment: `*mask` or `*it`?

Comment: So it is actually some arbitrary container, or is it specifically map/unordered_map? There are some possibilities to consider that would apply (for example) to a `vector` or `deque`, but not to a `map`/`unordered_map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::erase_if()`](//en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=erase_if) in a loop:

```
while (std::erase_if(your_set, your_predcate))
    /**/;
```

If you don't have C++20, don't despair. Cppreference.com gives an example implementation too.

If it proves to be a bottleneck, hand-rolling your own `all_erase_if()` with a specialization for node-based containers might be useful:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool has_node_type = requires { typename T::node_type; };
template <class T>
constexpr bool is_node_based = has_node_type<T>;

template <class C, class P>
auto all_erase_if(C& c, F f) requires is_node_based<C> {
    const auto old_size = std::size(c);
    if (!old_size)
        return old_size;
    auto it = std::begin(c), stop = std::begin(c);
    do {
        while (f(*it)) {
            it = stop = c.erase(it);
            if (it != std::end(c))
                /**/;
            else if (std::empty(c))
                return old_size;
            else
                it = stop = std::begin(c);
        }
        if (++it == std::end(c))
            it = std::begin(c);
    } while (it != stop);
    return old_size - std::size(c);
}

template <class C, class P>
auto all_erase_if(C& c, F f) requires !is_node_based<C> {
    const auto old_size = std::size(c);
    while (std::erase_if(c, std::ref(f)))
        /**/;
    return old_size - std::size(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to circle-iterate over the container until you have done a complete pass where you don't remove anything.

```
template<class C, class F>
void multi_pass_erase( C& c, F&& f )
{
  auto stop_at = c.end();
  auto it = current;
  while (true)
  {
    if (c.empty())
      return;
    if (f(*it))
    {
      it = c.erase(it);
      if (it == c.begin())
        stop_at = c.end();
      else
        stop_at = it;
    }
    else
    {
      ++it;
      if (it == stop_at)
        return;
    }
    if (it == c.end())
      it = c.begin();
  }
}
```

At the start of the loop, it refers to the next element to test, and only refers to end if the container is empty.

So if the container is empty, return.

`stop_at` tracks the element that, if we reach it, we have gone over the entire container and not found something to filter.

If we remove something, we note that the proper place to stop is after the element we erase.

If we don't remove something, we advance the iterator, and check if we should stop.

Then, if we have reached the end of the container, we go back to the start.

There is a bit of careful work where we test for "stop" before we move it from end back to begin, so we should never store `stop_at` as referring to `begin()`.

Now lets compare it to

```
while (true) {
  if (!std::erase_if( set, test ))
    break;
}
```

Imagine if each cycle removes one element.  This could require O(n^2) time.

`multi_pass_erase` doesn't do amazingly better in this case.  If each element causes the previous one to be erased, `multi_pass_erase` doesn't shave off any visits whatsoever; in both cases, you have to visit every non-removed node before you find the next node to remove.

Basically, all of the fancyness to `multi_pass_erase` shaves off an average of half an iteration of the set each call whenever there is at least 1 erase, as if we assume the last erase is randomly positioned, we skip doing an average of half of the container.

The added complexity is probably not worth it.

---

But can we write something more complex and more efficient?

Usually when you delete something that could cause other things to need deletion, you can get information about those other things.

Consider tracking that information, and only looking at those elements, instead of the entire list again.

```
template<class C, class Test, class Dependencies>
void dependent_erase( C& c, Test&& t, Dependencies&& d ) {
  auto it = c.begin();
  using key_type = typename C::key_type;
  std::vector<key_type> todo_list;
  while (it != c.end())
  {
    if (t(*it)) {
      d( *it, &todo_list );
      it = c.erase(it);
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }
  // remove duplicates:
  std::vector<key_type> next_todo_list;
  while (!todo_list.empty()) {
    // better to shrink the list and ask f(x) less often
    std::sort(todo_list.begin(), todo_list.end());
    todo_list.erase( std::unique(todo_list.begin(), todo_list.end()), todo_list.end() );
    for (auto&& todo : todo_list) {
      auto it = c.find( todo );
      if (f(*it))
      {
        d( *it, &next_todo_list );
        c.erase(it);
      }
    }
    todo_list = std::move( next_todo_list );
    next_todo_list.clear();
  }
}
```

here we have our Test t (do we want to delete this item?)  If we do, we call `d( item, vector* )` and store any direct dependencies we'd want to retest there.

We then go over the container, removing things as needed.  Then we go over the dependencies and remove anything mentioned that should go away, repeatedly until we no longer find new items to delete.

If we assume your code is a bunch of nodes with references to other nodes, and you are doing garbage collection, this should be far better in many cases.

...

Code not tested or even compiled.  But I've done this before, so it might work.  It should at least work as pseudo-code.

If you expect a LOT of dependencies per deleted node, and lots of overlap, a set-based todo list might be better than a vector one.  Ie, if you have N elements removed each with M dependencies, that vector grows to NM size.  But if M tends to be small and not have much overlap with other elements, then the vector will be much faster than a node-based set.